# Is "donc" in an imperative always an emphasis? Instead of meaning "therefore"?

Tags: sens

- Continue **donc** de te concentrer sur ~~~ !

In an imperative sentence, *donc* means "DO continue" as an emphasis, right? Instead of "so, therefore"?

If that is the case, how can you mean "so" in an imperative like this one? Should you use *alors*?

- **Alors** continue **donc** de te concentrer sur ~~~ !

In another case, in a "let's do ~~~" sentence, does *donc* mean "so"? Or "LET'S do ~~~" as an emphasis?

- Faisons **donc** un petit tour ~~~

Answer (score 4):

That's what the TLF says about [*donc*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/donc) in imperative sentences:

> **II**.− Particule servant à noter une réaction affective ou expressive devant une situation donnée, exprimée ou suggérée par le contexte (valeurs stylistiques en situation)
>   [...]
>   4. [impérative] Entrez donc, asseyez-vous donc, faites donc! Il dit d'une voix engageante : « Viens donc dîner un de ces soirs à la maison » (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 294).

The role of *donc* in an imperative sentence is to add feeling to your words. I read Simone de Beauvoir's sentence as expressing polite invites that could be rephrased as: *Donnez vous la peine de rentrer*<sup>1</sup>, *Et si tu venais dîner*<sup>2</sup>.
It is the same meaning in your sentence: *Faisons donc un petit tour.*<sup>3</sup>

In your other sentence:

> (Alors) Continue donc de te concentrer sur ~~~ !

it is a firm exhortation to act in a certain way. We could rephrase the sentence like this: *Veux-tu bien te concentrer...*  I don't understand what you mean when you say  "how can you mean "so" in an imperative like this one?" I don't see what meaning of *so* it could have here...
I would express the sentence in English as "Well then, will you please concentrate further on ~~~!"

I can't say *donc* will never express consequence in an imperative sentence, because one might find an instance where it does, but it doesn't to me in any of the sentences you gave.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Do come in.</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>What about coming to dinner...</sub> 
<sup>3</sup><sub>Let's go for a walk!/ What about going for a walk!</sub>

Comment: I'm thinking "in that case" may be a good translation for such sentences.